# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting '`' in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to show datas of my table room_tb in tabular form.but i have been getting this error.
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting "'" in line 44.
here is my code.Tell me what am i doing wrong because i could not figure out what is happening. I was working the other day but when today i opened my laptop that this error occurs.

```
 <?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('iwant2');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html lang="en">   
<head>   
<meta charset="utf-8">   
<title>Example of Zebra Table with twitter bootstrap</title>   
<meta name="description" content="Creating a Zebra table with Twitter Bootstrap. Learn with example of a Zebra Table with Twitter Bootstrap.">  
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">   
</head>  
<body>  
<table class="table table-striped">  
        <thead>  
          <tr>  
            <th>List</th>  
            <th>Price</th>  
            <th>Date</th>           
        </tr>  
        </thead>

        <?php
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM room_tb");
        if (!$result) 
        { 
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
        }
    ?>
        <tbody>
        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>

          <tr>  
            <td><?php echo $row[0] ?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $row[1] ?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $row[2] ?></td>  
          </tr>  
          <?php } ?>
          </tbody>  
      </table>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: You need to stop hitting the `\`` key.

Comment: Ticks are gone. Aahh "good boy Rex"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didnt close that middle section of PHP.

What you want is

```
    <?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM room_tb");
    if (!$result) 
    { 
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
`   }
    ?>
    <tbody>
   <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>

      <tr>  
        <td><?php echo $row[0] ?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $row[1] ?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $row[2] ?></td>  
      </tr>  
      <?php } ?>
      </tbody>  
  </table>  
</body>  
</html>
```

basically you're getting the error because you left a quote open somewhere im guessing. php was expecting it to close but instead came across the end of your file. look at the very end of the file for any random characters and make sure that you've closed all your php tags properly.

if you dont see anything at the end of the file, make sure theres not just a bunch of whitespace, the problem could be over the right margin.

Comment: i did correct that but it still is not working...and what do you mean by top hitting the ` key

Comment: @enjal [**Ticks are gone**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222139/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-expecting-in-php#comment26712226_18222139)

Comment: weird, when i saw the question originally, there was a random '`' at the end of your codeblock. edited my answer.

Comment: @castis That's because I got rid of 'em.

Comment: did you make sure and remove them from the end of your file that you're working on?

Comment: @castis ya i removed that ' sign with your help..but its still giving the same error in line 44